# Problem with the file .aux

Tags: auxiliary-files

I use the LaTeX and specific MikTeX and i have a problem.

I finish a text.It works good,i take the pdf.Now,if i do an error into preamble it won't run.a
Ok until now there isn't problem.Now i correct the false statement or command.The curiousness
is that i must delete the file ending with .aux to run the text.If i don't delete it,the latex can't translate the text into pdf,although,the preamble doesn't errors.

This is the problems.If someone could help me,i would be grateful.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear enough to answer, but it is the case that some errors will lead to a corrupt aux file which must then be deleted to enable later latex runs to complete.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  This is not a MikTeX specific question.  David Carlisle has already explains well what is happening.  An alternative to deleting the `aux` file is sometimes to simply compile two times in a row after the change.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As David Carlisle says, the solution is to delete the `.aux` file. Most errors will not create a corrupt `.aux` file and deleting it will not be necessary but sometimes it will and then you just delete it and continue.